# C# ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary

Tags: c#, expressionvisitor

**From: How to: Modify Expression Trees (C# and Visual Basic)**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546136.aspx

```
protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
    {
        if (b.NodeType == ExpressionType.AndAlso)
        {
            Expression left = this.Visit(b.Left);
            Expression right = this.Visit(b.Right);

            // Make this binary expression an OrElse operation instead of an AndAlso operation. 
            return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.OrElse, left, right, b.IsLiftedToNull, b.Method);
        }

        return base.VisitBinary(b);
    }
```

Fix me if Im wrong about the purpose of this method and how it is working. Thank you.

If I have an exsisting experssion, the Expresstion Visitor will send every BinaryExpression to this method so this two lines, from my understanding are a waste :

```
Expression left = this.Visit(b.Left);
Expression right = this.Visit(b.Right);
```

Becouse those two lines do the same thing, will be responsibole for every BinaryExpression to be sent to this method. Am I right?

Expression.MakeBinary purpose is to update the BinaryExpression to a new one. So why not to use this method: b.Update??

and last thing, is this method going to replace every AndAlso in to OrElse on this expression?

**thank you for your time in advance.**

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: "Becouse those two lines do the same thing, will be responsibole for every BinaryExpression to be sent to this method." Please clarify.

Comment: the Expresstion Visitor will send every BinaryExpression to this method and that two lines do the same so why write them too?